# Media queries not working as they should

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So, Ive come across a problem that I can't seem to figure out the cause of.

I have a few CSS files:

1) styles.css - contains most of the webpage's styling.

2) overlay.css - contains the styling for my overlay.

3) media.css - contains all the media queries.

So far, everything works great and my page acts responsively. However, for some reason, I can't make media queries work with my overlay. Here is my CSS for the overlay in the file overlay.css:

```
#aboutus {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -225px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Here is my media query in media.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #aboutus {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

At the moment this query has no effect whatsoever. The weird thing is, if I put the query under the code in overlay.css instead, it does work 100%.

Why is this so?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you load your css? Your media css should be on last after styles & overlay.css

Comment: That's what is is!! Knew it was simple. Thanks!

Comment: You can potentially put the css files in any order, but only if the css selectors have a higher specificity. For example, `#aboutus.x`

Comment: @Syahrul You probably solved OP's problem. Please add the comment as an answer.

Comment: @ThePragmatick I've added my comment as answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Do you have a live or test site to look at?

Answer (score 3):

How do you load your css? Your media css should be on last after styles & overlay.css